# Get payment type by order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Is possibile get payment type by order Id?
Example: Cash, Transfer, PayPal, Credit Card

Now I using: $order->payment_method_title but I need 'payment type'or 'payment category'

CC

Answer (score 0):

you can use `get_payment_method()` to get the payment method :

```
$order->get_payment_method()
```

**For more information:**

[WC_Order Class Reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html)